# Close button only for some tabs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, tabs

I am using Qt for an assignment I have for college, and I want to use `QTabWidget` to display a chat window much like [Pidgin's](https://www.pidgin.im/). I want to make the "group chat" tab always open and impossible to close and the rest of the "private channel" tabs closable.

`QTabWidget`'s `setTabsClosable(bool)` is not helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 41):

I found an easier solution, I think.
Simply access the relevant close button and resize it.

`tabWidget->tabBar()->tabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide)->resize(0, 0);`

Comment: I think this is even easier: 
`tabWidget->tabBar()->tabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide)->hide();`

Comment: The first approach is preferable since it reclaims the space used up by the button. This question should be upvoted to answer imo.

Comment: On the Mac using document tab mode, this will cause a runtime error because the tab button is on the left.

Comment: There's a typo in the answer: `tabButton()` returns a pointer, not the object itself. Unfortunately, SO requires at least 6 characters changed, so I can't submit an edit.

Comment: Even: tabWidget->tabBar()->tabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide, 0) which removes the button

Answer (score 18):

Find the bar (it is private, so use findChild()) and remove the buttons. Documentation claims that close buttons may be placed on left side too.

```
QTabBar *tabBar = ui->tabWidget->findChild<QTabBar *>();
tabBar->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide, 0);
tabBar->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::LeftSide, 0);
```

Comment: BTW QTabWidget::tabBar() is no longer protected

Answer (score 9):

Hallo,

I guess this post won't help the author of this thread but perhaps someone else wanders over here.

In most cases a non-closable tab should not only ignore the closevent it also should not show a close symbol in its corner. A nice way to reach this is to modify the QTabBar which is inside the QTabWidget.

Example:

```
// let tabWidget be a QTabWidget with at least one page

QPushButton *closeButton = new QPushButton();
// set icon and size for PushButton, ... 
// connect Signal clicked() from closeButton with Slot closeCurrentTab(), ...

// next line sets closeButton in right corner on tab with index 0
tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide, closeButton);
```

Comment: I wandered over here - thanks! it worked like a charm (in Python): style = QtGui.qApp.style() \
icon = style.standardIcon(style.SP_DockWidgetCloseButton) \
closeButton = QtGui.QPushButton(icon, '') \
closeButton.setStyleSheet('border-style: inset;')
self._detailTabs.tabBar().setTabButton(currentTab, QtGui.QTabBar.RightSide, closeButton)

Comment: For anybody else wondering here from Python, I wanted to hide the button completely and couldn't get it to work by setting an empty QPushButton. But passing `None` instead worked perfectly: `TabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(0, QTabBar.RightSide, None)`

Answer (score 4):

Although tabBar() is indeed protected, Klaus pointed into the right direction. Simply subclass QTabWidget and implement a wrapper method.

Comment: BTW QTabWidget::tabBar() is no longer protected

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can handle the tabCloseRequest signal and decide whether u'll close a given tab or not

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtabwidget.html#tabCloseRequested

Edit: I created a small example to check it out. My example is a simple QtGui application with a mainwindow that has a tabwidget. I then added the tabCloseRequested slot. Here is the code

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)
{
   if(someCondition){
       return;
   } else if(anotherCondition){
       ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
   }
}
```

From this example only tabs where the condition doesn't apply will be closed.

Comment: no, it will not help, because when signal received, event is already going to be done, and signal can't do anything.

Comment: I added tabCloseRequest slot in my response to clarify how it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should reimplement your widget's event(Event *e) method, check the type of e, find out CloseEvents, and call parent class's event when you can allow tab to close, or e->ignore() when you do not want it.

Note, then you must parent's event() handle othr events, so do not accept(), reject() or forget them Ж)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for adding a pushbutton to some tabs and not in other is to define a subclass of QTabWidget for taking the QTabBar that is a potected!
The code below is tested and it works:

```
//TabWidget.h

#ifndef TABWIDGET_H
#define TABWIDGET_H
#include <QTabWidget>

class TabWidget : public QTabWidget {
public:
    TabWidget(QWidget *parent);
    ~TabWidget();
    QTabBar *tabBar() const;
};
#endif  /* TABWIDGET_H */

//TabWidget.cpp

#include "TabWidget.h"
TabWidget::TabWidget(QWidget * p=0) : QTabWidget(p) {}

TabWidget::~TabWidget() {}

QTabBar * TabWidget::tabBar() const {return QTabWidget::tabBar();}
```

For using this subclass and create a new tab with a custom button you have to following this instructions ( ui->tabWidget is a QTabWidget with setClosableTabs=false):

```
TabWidget *t = (TabWidget *) ui->tabWidget;
t->addTab(new QWidget, "empty");
QTabBar *tab = t->tabBar();
QPushButton *b = new QPushButton();
b->setText("x");
tab->setTabButton(tab->count() -1, QTabBar::RightSide, b);
connect(b,SIGNAL(...),this,SLOT(...));
```

Comment: BTW QTabWidget::tabBar() is no longer protected

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why nobody here mentioned the simplest working solution:

```
tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide, 0);
```

This completely removes the close button, and the space taken by it.
[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#setTabButton)